# How to switch through attributes in XML XDocument XElement in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I know, there are tons of Post for this topic, but since I read two days during the posts and nothing worked, I decided to ask here.
I have a XML (Level01.xml) file like this

```
<map version="1.0">
 <tileset>
  <image source="....>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="background">
     <data encoding="csv">
     3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
     3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
     3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
     3,3,3,3,3,3,3
     </data>
 </layer>
 <layer name="walls">
     <data encoding="csv">
     182,182,182,182,182,8,8,
     182,8,182,8,8,8,8,
     182,182,182,182,182,8,8,
     182,8,182,8,8,8,8,
     </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Its a (tile-)map with different layers and I want to draw it in XNA. Therefore I want to read the data from each layer into a `string[]`
This is what I tried, but it doesn't work for the second `string[] walldata` and I am absolutely desperate because I don't understand why

```
public class LevelXmlReader
{
    public string[] backgroundData;
    public string[] wallData;

    LevelXmlReader()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Level/Level01.xml");
        foreach (XElement layer in doc.Element("map").Descendants("layer"))
        {

            var lay = doc.Element("map").Element("layer");
            var layName = lay.Attribute("name").Value;
            switch (layName)
            {
                case "background":
                    {
                        backgroundData = lay.Element("data").Value.Split(',');
                    }
                    break;
                case "walls":
                    {
                        wallData = lay.Element("data").Value.Split(',');
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

When I try to draw `wallData`, there is always the ExceptionError "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside your loop you are declaring

```
var lay = doc.Element("map").Element("layer");
```

this is unecessary, because you already HAVE the individual layer.  you need to remove that line entirely and use the `layer` variable from the foreach loop.  The inside of the loop should now look like this

```
foreach (XElement layer in doc.Element("map").Descendants("layer"))
{
    switch (layer.Attribute("name").Value)
    {
        case "background":       
            backgroundData = layer.Element("data").Value.Split(','); 
            break;

        case "walls":
            wallData = layer.Element("data").Value.Split(',');
            break;
    }
}
```

In your code, you're always grabbing the same layer both times, instead of stepping through them.

Comment: Go ahead and accept the answer then.  If you keep asking questions without crediting the correct answer, people get annoyed with you

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `foreach` to iterate all `layer` tags. But inside the loop, you are not using them. Instead, you are always accessing the first layer via `doc.Element("map").Element("layer")`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var lay = doc.Element("map").Element("layer");
```

with

```
var lay = layer;
```

You are ignoring the loop variable, while using only the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class LevelXmlReader
{
    public string[] backgroundData;
    public string[] wallData;

    LevelXmlReader()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Level/Level01.xml");
        foreach (XElement layer in doc.Element("map").Descendants("layer"))
        {
            var layName = layer.Attribute("name").Value;
            switch (layName)
            {
                case "background":
                    backgroundData = layer.Element("data").Value.Split(',');
                    break;

                case "walls":
                    wallData = layer.Element("data").Value.Split(',');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```